# How to call StyleSelector on PropertyChanges of a row

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have RowStyleSelector with datagrid.
It's called correctly on load of the window.
On changes of rows when I call PropertyChange it's not called.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ColumnWidth="*"  ItemsSource="{Binding TraceItemCollectionViewSource , Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" EnableRowVirtualization="false"  RowStyleSelector="{StaticResource TraceRowStyleSelector}" IsReadOnly="True" Name="TraceDataGrid" Margin="5,5,5,5" Padding="5,5,5,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

This is my model:

```
public class TraceDataItem :  ObservableObject
{

    private string _newReelId;
    public string NewReelId
    {
        get { return _newReelId; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _newReelId)
            {
                _newReelId = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("NewReelId");
            }
        } 
    }


}
```

How I can make `RowStyleSelector` to be called when `PropertyChanged("NewReelId")` is called .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StyleSelector` doesn't listen to `PropertyChange` notifications. However you can use `DataTrigger` based on a Boolean property instead:

```
bool _reelIdChanged;
public bool ReelIdChanged 
{
    get { return _reelIdChanged; }
    set
    {
        _reelIdChanged = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ReelIdChanged");
    }
}

private string _newReelId;
public string NewReelId
{
    get { return _newReelId; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _newReelId)
        {
            _newReelId = value;
            ReelIdChanged = true;
            RaisePropertyChanged("NewReelId");
        }
        else
            ReelIdChanged = false;
    } 
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="TraceRowStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DataBackground}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ReelIdChanged }" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" 
              ColumnWidth="*"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding TraceItemCollectionViewSource  , Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              EnableRowVirtualization="false"  
              RowStyle="{StaticResource TraceRowStyle}" 
              IsReadOnly="True"
              Name="TraceDataGrid" 
              Margin="5,5,5,5" 
              Padding="5,5,5,5" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
```